# Swift Function Input Generic Conform To Both Class And Protocol

Tags: swift, generics, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to have a function take a generic input that conforms to both a class and a protocol in order to process values where some belong to the class and others belong to the delegate. It works fine for individual types, but not for an array of types (which conform to both the super class and the delegate). Instead the compiler throws the error "Instance method 'printValues(for:)' requires that 'MeasurementClass' conform to 'UnitDelegate'"

I've added the code below, which will make much more sense. Just put it in a Swift Playground. If you run it as is, you can see that it properly prints the users distance and steps individually. If you uncomment the last few lines, the same function cannot be used with an array.

My goal is to be able to pass an array of types that conform to the UnitDelegate and MeasurementClass (aka MeasurementObject typealias) and have the values processed. I want an array, because I will need up having a bunch of different classes that conform to MeasurementObject.

```
protocol UnitDelegate: class{
    var units: [String: String] { get }
}

class MeasurementClass{
    var imperial: Double!
    var metric: Double!
    
    convenience init(imperial: Double, metric: Double){
        self.init()
        self.imperial = imperial
        self.metric = metric
    }
}

typealias MeasurementObject = MeasurementClass & UnitDelegate


class Distance: MeasurementObject{
    var units = ["imperial": "miles", "metric":"kms"]
}

class Steps: MeasurementObject{
    var units = ["imperial": "steps", "metric":"steps"]
}

class User{
    func printValues<T: MeasurementObject>(for type: T) {
        print("\(type.imperial!) \(type.units["imperial"]!) = \(type.metric!) \(type.units["metric"]!)")
    }
}

//This is what I'm trying to achieve in the for loop below
let distance = Distance(imperial: 30, metric: 48.28)
let steps    = Steps(imperial: 30, metric: 30)
let user     = User()
user.printValues(for: distance)
user.printValues(for: steps)


//let types = [distance, steps]
//
//for type in types{
//    user.printValues(for: type)
//}
```

Comment: This is not how generic works. You can not mix generic types in a collection. A generic type can be any type but only one at a time

Comment: `    var imperial: Double!
    var metric: Double!` I guarentee you that these two values will go out of sync. Store only one source of truth, e.g. the standard metric value, and make the imperial measurement a computed property that derives the correct conversion on the fly. That way, it can never go out of sync

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I thought about that and decided that this is the best. I'm storing a bunch of health types on a server and by having imperial and metric stored, I can just pull out the correct value. If I only had imperial, I would have to somehow switch on the type of data being pulled down to do the conversion. By having all of the health records stored with the same values on the server, on the native app side I can use a single class to decode every type.

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon I'm suggesting you privilege one value as the only one worth storing. Take a look at the [Units and Measurement API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/units_and_measurement) Apple built into Foundation. From what little I've seen of your code/problem, it looks like an exact fit for what you're trying to do. If not, you could at least reference it, such as their base units: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dimension

Comment: I had no idea about this, it’s is going to be perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question but all you need is to add an enumeration to store the kind of measurement to your class, and a computed property to return the corresponding dictionary. No need to use a protocol, protocol composition, class and/or subclass to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
struct AMeasurement {
    let imperial: Double
    let metric: Double
    let kind: Kind
    enum Kind { case distance, steps }
    var units: [String: String] {
        switch kind {
        case .distance: return ["imperial": "miles", "metric":"kms"]
        case .steps: return ["imperial": "steps", "metric":"steps"]
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension AMeasurement {
    func printValues() {
        print("\(imperial) \(units["imperial"]!) = \(metric) \(units["metric"]!)")
    }
}
```

---

```
let distance = AMeasurement(imperial: 30, metric: 48.28, kind: .distance)
let steps = AMeasurement(imperial: 30, metric: 30, kind: .steps)
let types = [distance, steps]

for type in types {
    type.printValues()
}
```

> 30.0 miles = 48.28 kms
> 30.0 steps = 30.0 steps

Comment: This is a much easier approach to solve my problem. I seem to of been over complicating the answer. Thanks for the help!